# What causes the following difference in implicit lambda capture behavior?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17

The following compiles fine, `N` is implicitly captured in the lambda `fn` (C++17):

```
void f()
{ 
  const int N{42};
  auto fn = []() { return N; };
}
```

(https://godbolt.org/z/JpyZHC)

The following does not compile (`delay` is not captured), and I have a hard time figuring out what the exact reason is. Because `delay` is not a POD? After reading cppreference.com it seems it has something to do with ODR-usage, but I fail to grasp what the significant difference between `N` and `delay` is in terms of ODR-usage. Changing `const` to `constexpr` below does not make a difference.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void g()
{
  using namespace std::chrono_literals; 
  const auto delay{42ms};
  auto fn = []() { std::this_thread::sleep_for(delay); };
}
```

(https://godbolt.org/z/XA3WCR)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::this_thread::sleep_for` takes it's parameter by reference.  This means that it needs to ODR-use `delay` and that requires that the lambda capture `delay`.

In your first example you do not ODR-use `N` so it's not required that it be captured.